# Inner product deduced from norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Consider $H=\lbrace x\in l^2:\Sigma_{k\geq1}k^2|x_k|^2<\infty\rbrace$. I have this norm $\|·\|_H:H\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $\|x\|_H=(\Sigma_{k\geq1}k^2|x_k|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. And I need to calculate its inner product.

I used parallelogram law and calculated its inner product as $\langle x,y\rangle=\Sigma_{k\geq1}k^2x_ky_k$. I'm not sure whether I calculated this correct. Does the inner product should be $\langle x,y\rangle=\Sigma_{k\geq1}k^2|x_ky_k|$? What is the correct inner product?

Comment: What is the space $H$? Anyway, looks like the inner product should be $\sum_{k\geq 1} k^2x_k\overline{y_k}$.

Comment: @Mark Space H is $H=\lbrace x\in l^2:\Sigma_{k\geq1}k^2|x_k|^2<\infty\rbrace$. And we consider it is in the real space.

Comment: If the space is real you don't need to conjugate $y_k$. So it is $\sum_{k\geq 1} k^2x_ky_k$.

Comment: If your components $x_k$ are real numbers, you can omit the complex conjugation in @Mark's comment.  Of course if they are real numbers, your absolute value signs in defining the normed space $H$ are redundant.  So your first expresssion using the parallelogram law was correct (leave out the absolute value signs).